# How to read ifstream from unsigned char?

Tags: c++, ifstream

I have unsigned char like below.

```
unsigned char out[CHUNK];
```

Which is decompressed by zlib.

I need ifstream to read from that unsigned char without saving into temp files.

```
ifstream file;
```

What options do I have?

Comment: Why do you *need* an `ifstream`? If your functions take `ifstream&` parameters then they should take `istream&`s instead, and then you can use `istringstream`.

Comment: What are you going to achieve with that? Are you using some third party lib (function)? And could you provide more code, please.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of ifstream, you need stringstream. You can use it as follows:

```
#include <sstream>
stringstream file(out);

int value;
file >> value;
```

The documentation of stringstream is available at: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/sstream/stringstream/stringstream/